# Object into excel file - pandas

Tags: excel, pandas

I got an object in format:

```
{
    "methodName_1": {
        "version_1": "count",
        "version_2": "count"
    },
    "methodName_2": {
        "version_1": "count",
        "version_2": "count"
    },
    ...
}
```

How can I write it into excel in format:

```
               version_1, version_2, ...
methodName_1:  count, count, ...
methodName_2:  count, count, ...
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Dataframe` constructor and transpose or [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html), last write to excel by [`DataFrame.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T
#alternative
#df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
print (df)
             version_1 version_2
methodName_1     count     count
methodName_2     count     count


df.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```